# 1, 333, 55555, .... find an expresion for the general term

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

$$1, 333, 55555, ....$$

My work:
If $n\in [u^2+1, (u+1)^2]$,
then $a_n = 2u+1$ for $u=0,1,2,\ldots$

This seems to work but is it possible to have a nice expression for the general term without conditions?

Comment: It looks to continue with $7777777,999999999$, but then what?  Is it $122222222221$? or $1111111111111111111111$?  or what?

Comment: It is unclear what you would expect when $n \ge 10$..

Comment: sorry I'll edit the question one sec @hardmath

Comment: @RossMillikan kindly see the question now. sorry i wrote the sequence wrong before

Comment: @across I've rolled back your question, because answering it took some effort. If you want to change it so significantly, please ask another one

Comment: @Andronicus ok fine actually i feel the  incorrect question is more interesting than my original question. Im still going through your answer. Thanks!

Comment: $(2n+1)\frac{10^{2n+1}} 9$  is the general term.

Comment: @sirous Do you mean $(2n-1)\tfrac{10^{2n-1}-1}{9}$?

Comment: @soheil, yes, it was a typo.

Answer (score 2):

If I am interpreting the query correctly, you want $\left(2 \times \lceil\sqrt{n}\rceil\right) - 1,$ where $\lceil x\rceil$ is the ceiling function (smallest integer $\geq x$).

Comment: Slick! Exactly what I've been trying... thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Here are some ideas:

1. If you're allowed to use the sum:

$$(2n + 1 - 10\lfloor\frac{2n + 1}{10}\rfloor)\sum_{i=0}^{2n + 1}10^i$$

2. The sum can be rewritten as:

$$(2n + 1 - 10\lfloor\frac{2n + 1}{10}\rfloor)(10^{2(n + 1)} - 1)$$

3. The first term can also be rewritten:

$$(10\left\{\frac{2n + 1}{10}\right\})(10^{2(n + 1)} - 1)$$

In each form the first term extracts consecutive odd numbers in a circular way: $1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 1, 3, \dots$ whereas the second term is of the form $11\dots1$.

You can mix them as you want.

Comment: Note that OP has changed the sequence significantly

Comment: mathematical musical chairs